# How to pass function parameter inside named callback

Tags: javascript

Having the following code:

```
 var test1 = function(param){
    verify(callback);
}

var callback = function(){
    console.log(param);
}

var verify = function(inside){
   inside();
}

test1('I am the param');
```

how can I make available value of `param` inside the callback, so the console output would be 'I am the param';

If, instead of using `callback` I use an anonymous function, it works:

```
var test1 = function(param){
    verify(function(){
        console.log(param);
    });
}

var verify = function(inside){
   inside();
}

test1('I am the param');
```

Comment: callback refers to a variable called param that I don't see a definition for.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Take your solution, but call `callback(param)` inside the anonymous function and define a parameter on the `callback` function. No need to alter your functions then, if that was a concern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `callback` function does not know the value of `param`.

You can fix it by passing the `param` separately.

```js
var test1 = function(param1){
  verify(callback, param1);
}

var callback = function(param3){
  console.log(param3);
}

var verify = function(inside, param2){
  inside(param2);
}

test1('I am the param');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a decorator for the callback that returns a function. It is a bit hard to find a solution out of context. But I will try an example

```
var test1 = function(param){
   verify(callback(param));
}

var callback = function(param){
    return function(){
         console.log(param);
     }
}

var verify = function(inside){
   inside();
}

test1('I am the param');
```